# Vector data for Volcanic Ash Advisory Centre (VAAC) regions?

Tags: data-request, global, public-transport, geohazard

I would like to use the boundaries of the VAAC regions, as a layer in a GIS I am building.  I can find images of various <sup>(1)</sup> quality/extents, but no vector data.

For example, Wikipedia provides the following map ([image details](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VAAC_Coverage.jpg)), though it is out of date because there are no longer any parts of the globe not covered by a VAAC (see [link](http://vaac.metservice.com/images/vaacregions.jpg) to Wellington map below).

Does anyone know if such an open vector dataset exists?

Obviously some of the boundaries are defined by latitudes and longitudes, but the squiggly bits are defined by Flight Information Regions (FIRs); so if there are any open vector datasets that exist for FIRs, that would be useful too.

[image: Map showing the coverage of the nine worldwide Volcanic Ash Advisory Centers]

<sup>1</sup> Maps of VAACs provided by the VAACs are: 
[London](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/mohippo/media/image/5/c/vaacmap2014-522x273.jpg), [Toulouse](http://www.meteo.fr/vaac/CarteVAAC.jpg), [Anchorage](http://vaac.arh.noaa.gov/images/current_status_big.png), [Washington DC](http://www.ssd.noaa.gov/img/VAAC_areas_2005.jpg), [Tokyo](http://ds.data.jma.go.jp/svd/vaac/data/image/VAACarea_en.png), [Buenos Aires](http://www.smn.gov.ar/vaac/buenosaires/images/planetavacc.jpg), [Wellington](http://vaac.metservice.com/images/vaacregions.jpg), [Darwin](http://www.bom.gov.au/info/vaac/VAAC_map_2011.png), Montreal ~ no map found

Answer (score 1):

This file is really hard to find. But maybe parse http://www.ospo.noaa.gov/Products/atmosphere/vaac/boundaries.js
and share the result?

Parsing that .js was messy -- instead I made a GeoTIFF:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rzQPsP9rKa8eAMuRigjCazeGg1bLHsIq

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't include Montreal

Answer (score 1):

Through the [ICAO's GIS server](https://gis.icao.int/ArcGIS/rest/services/), you can get a KMZ file of the [2016 vintage VAAC regions](https://gis.icao.int/ArcGIS/rest/services/VOLCANO/MapServer/2/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=1%3D1&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=*&f=kmz).